# Gnome terminal filled with weird characters at random

Tags: gnome-terminal, unicode

Sometimes when I run a python terminal application of mine, I get weird characters all over the place. See screenshot. This only happens once in ten times.

I haven't seen this happen in other terminals. What's going on?

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

It is a bug in your Python code. The characters are all Unicode 001B, U+001B is the escape character. Your terminal is rendering it as a box with 001B inside. Your Python program is printing escape characters to the terminal, which is interpreting them as Unicode characters. You can reproduce this easily:

```
$ python
Python 2.7.7rc1 (default, May 21 2014, 11:15:30) 
[GCC 4.8.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> print chr(0x001b)
```